A countable intersections of derived sets
This question is from Hrbacek and Jech's intro set theory book (Ch 10, exercise 4.6). I am given:
$$F=\{1\}\cup\{1-\frac{1}{2^{n_1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n_1+n_2}}-...-\frac{1}{2^{n_1+...+n_k}} : k\leq n_1 \text{ and }n_i \geq 1 \text{ for all } i\leq k\}.$$
The notation here seems sort of vague to me, but I am interpreting the $k$, $n_1$ and $n_i$ to be variables in the naturals in particular (so $k$ is not a fixed constant, it is being quantified over in the definition of F). Please correct me if this is wrong.
The actual exercise is to show $F$ satisfies $F_\omega = \{1\}$ where $F_\omega = \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n$ for $F_n$ the nth derived set of $F$.
For what I have tried so far, I have let:
$$A_0=\{1\}$$
and for each natural number $m$
$$A_m = \{1-\frac{1}{2^{n_1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n_1+n_2}}-...-\frac{1}{2^{n_1+...+n_m}} : m\leq n_1 \text{ and }n_i \geq 1 \text{ for all } i\leq k\}$$
So now for $A_m$ the value $m$ is a fixed rather than quantified over.
From this I have defined:
$$B_m = \bigcup_{k=0}^m A_k.$$
It should follow:
$$F=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty B_m.$$
Using work from a previous exercise I'm pretty sure I can show $B_m \subseteq (B_{m+1})'$, for each choice of $m$ and from $B_n \subseteq F$ it should follow by taking derived sets $n$ times on both sides that $\{1\}\subseteq F_n$, thus $\{1\}\subseteq F_\omega$.
I know next I need to show every element of $F_\omega$ is $1$. So I have tried letting $y$, be an element of $F_\omega$, but I have no idea why $y$ can't be some value other than $1$?

Have you been able to find $F'$?

No, I don't really know what $F'$ is explicitly either. I had originally wanted to say $B_m =  (B_{m+1})'$. Then if I pick a point $x\in F$, I have $x\in B_m$, for some $m$. It will follow $x\in (B_{m+1})'\subseteq F'$ so that $F\subseteq F'$. But I'm not really sure of the exact set for $F'$ or if $B_m=(B_{m+1})'$ even really holds. @BrianMoehring

Well, I don't have a proof, but it would seem $$F_n={1}\cup{1-\frac{1}{2^{n_1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n_1+n_2}}-...-\frac{1}{2^{n_1+...+n_k}} : k+n\leq n_1 \text{ and }n_i \geq 1 \text{ for all } i\leq k}.$$ (I'll come back to this tomorrow if nobody has answered it by then)

Hello @BrianMoehring I tried working out some of the details from your hint in an answer. Is what I have similar to the approach you had in mind?

For ease of notation and to introduce some combinatorial objects of significant interest (the Schreier families), I'm going to work with a homeomorph of $F$ rather than with $F$ itself. Note that derivations commute with taking images under a homeomorphism, so working with a homeomorph is equivalent.
For more information on the Schreier families, look at section $3$ here and the references therein.
First note that if $p,q\in\{\cup \}\mathbb{N}$ and $1\leqslant i_1<\ldots < i_p$, $1\leqslant j_1<\ldots < j_q$ satisfy $$\sum_{k=1}^p 2^{-i_k}=\sum_{k=1}^q 2^{-j_k},$$ then $p=q$ and $i_k=j_k$ for all $1\leqslant k\leqslant p$. This is just uniqueness of binary representation, so we'll skip it.
Let $2^\mathbb{N}$ denote the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ and endow $2^\mathbb{N}$ with the Cantor topology (the topology making $E\leftrightarrow 1_E\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ a homeomorphism, where $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ has the product of the disctrete topology). We obey the convention that $\min \varnothing=\omega$ and that $\max \varnothing=0$.
Define $$G=\Bigl\{|E|: \min E\geqslant |E|\Bigr\}.$$  This is just the Schreier set.
I claim that $G$ is homeomorphic to $F$ via $$E\overset{f}{\mapsto} 1-\sum_{j\in E}\frac{1}{2^j}.$$  We obey the convention that the empty sum is zero, so $f(\varnothing)=1-0=1$. For $E\neq \varnothing$, if we write $E=\{m_1,\ldots, m_k\}$ with $m_1<\ldots<m_k$, then define $n_1=m_1$ and $n_i=m_i-m_{i-1}$ for each $1<i\leqslant k$.  Then $$f(E)=1-\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{2^{n_1+\ldots+n_i}}\in F.$$  So $f$ does indeed map into $f$. Injectivity follows from uniqueness of representation. Of course, $1=f(\varnothing)\in f(G)$, and $$1-\frac{1}{2^{n_1}}-\ldots - \frac{1}{2^{n_1+\ldots + n_k}}=F(E),$$ where $E=\{n_1, n_1+n_2,\ldots, n_1+n_2+\ldots + n_k\}$.    So $f$ is a surjection.
We will show that $f$ is continuous. We will use that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is metrizable, so it suffices to check sequential continuity. Fix $(E_q)_{q=1}^\infty \subset G$ with $E_q\to E\in G$.  Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and $p>\max E$ so large that $2^{-p}<\varepsilon$.  By definition of the product topology, there exists $q_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $q\geqslant q_0$, $$[1,p]\cap E=[1,p]\cap E_q.$$   But this means that for all $q\geqslant q_0$, $$|f(E)-f(E_q)|=\sum_{j\in E_q\setminus [1,p]}2^{-j}\leqslant \sum_{j=p+1}^\infty 2^{-j}=2^{-p}<\varepsilon.$$  This gives continuity.
We next show that $G$ is compact. Since $2^\mathbb{N}$ is compact metrizable, it is sufficient to show that $G$ is sequentially closed. Fix $(E_q)_{q=1}^\infty\subset G$ which is convergent to some $E\in 2^\mathbb{N}$. Seeking a contradiction, assume that $E\in 2^\mathbb{N}\setminus G$. This means $\min E<|E|$. In particular, $E$ is not empty. Let $n_1=\min E$.   Let $p=\max E$ and note that, for sufficiently large $q$, $$E=[1,p]\cap E= [1,p]\cap E_q.$$ But then $$|E_q|\geqslant |[1,p]\cap E_q|=|E|>\min E$$ and $$\min E_q=\min E,$$ so $$\min E_q<|E_q|,$$ contradicting the fact that $E_q\in G$.   This shows that $G$ is closed, and therefore compact.
Since $f:G\to F$ is a continuous bijection from the compact set $G$ into the Hausdorff set $F$, it is a homeomorhpism.
Thus it suffices to work with $G$.  I claim that for all $p<\omega$, $$G^p=\Bigl\{E\in 2^\mathbb{N}:|E|+p\leqslant \min E\Bigr\}.$$  The $p=0$ case is true by definition if $G$.  Assume that $$G^p=\Bigl\{E:|E|+p\leqslant \min E\Bigr\}.$$  Fix some $E$ with $|E|+p+1\leqslant \min E$.  Define $E_q=E\cup \{\max E+q\}$ for $q=1,2,\ldots$.  Then $E\neq E_q\to E$ and $$\min E_q=\min E\geqslant |E|+p+1=|E_q|+p.$$  So $E_q\in G^p$ and $E\in G^{p+1}$.  On the other hand, suppose $E\in G^{p+1}$ and fix a sequence $(E_q)_{q=1}^\infty \subset G^p\setminus \{E\}$ with $\lim_q E_q=E$.  Then for $p=\max E$ and all sufficiently large $q$, $$E=[1,p]\cap E=[1,p]\cap E_q.$$  Fix such a $q$.  Since $E\subset E_q$ and $E\neq E_q$, $|E_q|>|E|$.  We also have that $\min E=\min E_q$. Therefore $$|E|+p+1\leqslant |E_q|+p\leqslant \min E_q=\min E,$$ so $$G^{p+1}\subset \Bigl\{E:|E|+p+1\leqslant \min E\Bigr\}.$$ This gives our claim on $G^p$.
Note that since $\min E=\omega>0=|\varnothing|$, $E\in G^\omega$. On the other hand, for any non-empty $E\in G$, if $p\geqslant \min E$, then $$|E|+p>p\geqslant \min E,$$ and $E\notin G^p$. Therefore $G^\omega=\{\varnothing\}$.
Going back through the homeomorphism, $F^\omega=\{f(\varnothing)\}=\{1\}$.

The following is an attempt to work through some of the details from Brian Moehring's hint in the comments.
Let $$C_n=\{1\}\cup\{1-\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n_1+...+n_j}}:n_1\geq k+n \text{ and for all } i\leq k \text{ we have } n_i\geq 1\}.$$
Take $y\in C_1-\{1\}$ so that
$$y=1-\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n_1+...+n_j}},$$ where $n_1\geq k+1$ and each $n_j\geq 1$.
Now take $y_m\in F$ where
$$y_m=1-\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{2^{n_1+...+n_j}},$$
where we let $n_{k+1}=m$. Thus $\{y_m\}\to y$, hence $y\in F'$.
Next assume $y\in F'$ hence we may pick a sequence of points in $F-\{y\}$ indexed by $k$, converging to $y$ that satisfies
$$\Bigg|y-\Bigg(1-\sum_{j=1}^{N_k}\frac{1}{2^{n_{k_1} + ... + n_{k_j} }}\Bigg)\Bigg|<\frac{1}{2^k}$$
where $n_{k_1} \geq N_k$ and each $n_{k_j}\geq 1$ for each $k$.
If $\{N_k\} \to \infty$, then $\{N_k\}$ contains a strictly increasing sequence, so we may assume without loss of generality that $\{N_k\}$ is strictly increasing. It will follow the sum in the inequality shown above is bounded above by $\frac{N_k}{2^{N_k}}$, which tends to 0, thus $y=1$ follows by taking limits in $k$.
If $\{N_k\}\not\to\infty$, then $\{N_k\}$ as a set of naturals is bounded hence finite and thus
$$y=1-\sum_{j=1}^{N_m}\frac{1}{2^{n_{m_1} + ... + n_{m_j}}},$$
for some $m$. This shows $y\in F$, thus $y\in B_r\subseteq (B_{r+1})'$ using previous notation for some choice of $r$. So without loss of generality we may select the elements of our sequence above converging to $y$ from $B_{r+1}$. Thus $y\in B_{r+1}\subseteq C_1$ will follow.
We have now established $F'=C_1$
We iterate this procedure to show $F_n=C_n$ and then verify the intersection of the $C_n$'s is $1$ to establish our result.
